# Gmail: How do I know which address this mailing list email is sent to?

Tags: email, gmail

I have multiple email addresses linked to my Gmail account.

I am signed up to an email group where the messages I receive are sent to:

```
To: all-users@some-group.com
```

My email address is not shown. How do I find out which email address this was addressed to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `Delivered-To` portion of the email header. This will show the actual address the email was sent to.

It's usually the first line before the rest of the information:

```
Delivered-To: your.address@example.com
Received: by XX.XXX.X.XXX with SMTP id XXX
    Thu, 13 Aug 2009 05:25:18 -0700 (PDT)
```

To see the full header information, click on the **down arrow** next to the Reply option on the email and click **Show original**. This is usually at the top right of the email itself.

[image: show original menu]

Note that some themes and skins may move the menus around.

Comment: Your image is broken. Do you have the original image that you can reupload?

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't displayed in the full headers, you'll probably need to log into the email accounts individually and check.